# How to get Windows 7 to auto-login a user based on presence of wifi or bluetooth device?

Tags: windows-7, security, login, automation, authentication

I want to avoid the tediousness of typing the password for my user account on the many times each day that it wakes from sleep, but I want it to require the password whenever it's possible that it has been stolen.

Is there a way to get Win 7 to look for the presence of a predefined wifi network and/or a specific bluetooth device, and if found auto-login the user?

Comment: Back when you asked the question there wasn't an easy way.  Now, in September 2017 there is Bluetooth 4.0 and driver software that does this.  Also, in my answer you can see other software to control it.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I personally think it can't be done. Why?
It's because Windows doesn't scan for WiFi hotspots when it's locked.

But you can do the same for a USB device.

We already have a [older topic](https://superuser.com/questions/209341/logging-into-windows-using-usb-key)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that describes how to use your cellphone as a bluetooth proximity tag.  When your phone is near your computer it will stay logged in.

[How to Lock Your Computer With Bluetooth Proximity Lock Utility](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/lock-windows-computer-bluetooth-proximity-lock-utility/)

It shows how to download a utility that will automatically lock your computer when you go away, and how to log back in.

This comes up on my Windows 7 machine every time I turn it on, because I installed the drivers for a new Bluetooth 4.0 dongle.  The setup is in the program.

---

Conversely, if your computer is showing this but you don't want it, here is Microsoft's advice on the subject:

[Bluetooth Security Tag Login HOW TO Remove it](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/bluetooth-security-tag-login-how-to-remove-it/d74a1be1-7097-4157-9277-162b1d1d02e6)

Note that this MS article is about Windows 10.  Yet it works on my Win7 computer.